# Split a list and rejoin it using the same separator

Tags: python, string

Take the following string:

```
"Hello,world,how-are you?h"
```

If I were to split it using:

```
import re
x = re.split("[^a-zA-Z]", string)
```

I would get:

```
["Hello","world","how","are","you","h"]
```

Then, to each element of the new list I would run a function, say:

```
y = map(str.upper, x)
```

How could I rejoin it using the original separators? In the above example, the rejoining process would result with:

```
"HELLO,WORLD,HOW-ARE-YOU?H"
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `re.split()` for that, since you no longer have the delimiter that was used to split the string, after splitting, what exactly are you trying to do? Is it that for every word, you want to run some function?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes, exactly

Comment: Why are "are" and "you" separated by a space in the input, and a hyphen in the final output? Is that a typo, or do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](https://devdocs.io/python2/library/re#re.sub) instead:

```
import re
def change(m):
  return str.upper(m.group(0))
x = re.sub("[a-zA-Z]", change, string)
```

Comment: the parameter that the function receives would be a match object, you would need to use `.group()` to get the string from it, within the function (or use lambda to send the result of `.group()` to the function) .

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yeah. Just fixed it. Thanks

Comment: How would this work if I were to use an anonymous function where `change` is?

Comment: @BetaDecay `lambda` function?

Comment: @hjpotter92 When I try it, it complains with an error. Something along the lines of *put brackets around a generator function*

Comment: @hjpotter92 Ah no it's fine now thanks, I had an errant for loop :P

Comment: @BetaDecay I was reading that question a little while ago :P. Anyway, you should know that `\w` includes `_` characters as well.